# How do I get database instance in grails?

Tags: java, mysql, grails, groovy

I'm novice in Grails and I have a doubt. Lets say I have my `Datasource.groovy` configured to `mysql` database. Everything works fine and my grails app is running.

In the controller, if I want to add/modify the database that I have set in `DataSource.groovy` how I can do that?

Again I need to do something like this in each controller :

```
def db = Sql.newInstance(
                    'jdbc:mysql://*****',
                    'root',
                    '',
                    'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
                )
```

in order to get the db instance that I point to `DataSource.groovy` file?

Are there any best practices to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this (I would recommend this is done in a Service rather than a Controller, as it will make your controllers cleaner and you code easier to follow)

```
import groovy.sql.Sql 

class DataSourceAccessingService {
  def datasource

  def runSomeQuery( String sql ) {
    def sql = new Sql( datasource )
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh even `DataSource.groovy` can be injected! Thats great about grails!